# Call azure DevOps API from custom azure webapp api without user behalf

Tags: azure, rest, asp.net-core, authentication

I have an Azure WebApp which needs to call the Azure DevOps API to trigger a build pipeline.
The only problem I have is to find out which is the proper way to authenticate from my web api against azure devops API.

Should I use a service principal account for that, or Managed Identity?
Do I have to create a service account in Azure AD, give him rights on Azure DevOps ?

I only have a route which then calls the DevOps API, so I need to authenticate at the moment the route was called with a Principal from the WebApp.

Iam a little bit lost how to do it the right way, because there is so much information about the auth topic.

Currently I use my personal account with PAT from Azure KeyVault, which is only a temporary solution.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you check this [Choose the right authentication mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops) document, you will find several types of authentication mechanism from your Web App API against azure DevOps API.

But it's mostly recommended to **use Azure DevOps Services Client Libraries for authentication and accessing Azure DevOps Services resources.** You can authenticate your web app users for REST API access, so your app doesn't continue to ask for usernames and passwords.

Azure DevOps Services uses the OAuth 2.0 protocol to authorize your app for a user and generate an access token. Use this token when you call the REST APIs from your application. When you call Azure DevOps Services APIs for that user, use that user's access token. Access tokens expire, so refresh the access token if it's expired.

I would suggest to read this [Authorize access to REST APIs with OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops) document for the more explanation and detailed approach to achieve the result.

In case, if any required functionality is missing from the client libraries, [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview) is an alternative authentication mechanism to use with our REST APIs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. The Problem is: I have no User which is authenticated, only a web app which calls the DeVOps API.